# My explanation of six realms of existence

Tags: teaching, buddhist

**The six realms states of mind**

This is my graphical interpretation of existence of six realms by Buddha.

[image]

I have attempted to decode the great concept of Buddhist teaching consider the state of mind as all beings possess the mind:

- X axis represent the level of mind or level of happiness and suffering which can’t be measured by scientific apparatus.
- Y axis represents time which only feels by mind and time can’t be measured. (Absolute time)

White paper represents space.

1. God’s realm

   Here is it. Gods are always in happy mind and maintain it effortlessly long time and happiness is stable.

   Time is very fast as they are in happiness and pleasure. Their physical body has been evolved to feel and maintain the happiness and pleasure. Human can’t measure anything on this realm except feel the state of mind just a few seconds or minutes.

   No 1 represent this in graphical way e.g. poor, financially oppressed human has collected the bundle of 1 million dollar notes. So his happiness suddenly reached his climax and enjoy the pleasure and overflow his happiness for few seconds or few minute etc……. and once he feel the fear of robbers, hesitations of the future and thinking about what to do in future and he is collapsed on human level of human mind again. If he is with cardiac problem then he is dropped down to hell being as suffer cardiac pain or death as can’t control his thought and overflow of happiness. Time is extremely fast on this realm.
2. Demi gods or Asura

   Normally Demi-gods are below the gods. They are confident on their power of fighting nature. Intelligent and born to fight. Physical body has been designed for it. Muscular, strong body, intelligent and master on weapon usage and create new weapons. They are born to survival and they normally not possess for survival. But someone on craving and try to possess in front of Asuras, they will fight for grab it even though the object is useless for them. Once they possess the object they are in climax of happiness and fade it gradually with time. E.g. this can be experienced with kids some time neglected toy get the attention child the second child also come with desire for same toy and they will fight for it.

   Time is fast and varies in this realm.
3. Humans realm

   They can think the middle way. That’s the reason Buddha specially states about Human realm. Any psychiatric can explain the human mind. Time is average in this realm
4. Animal realm

   Driven by instincts and ever one know range of physical appearance. No spiritual vision, no religion, no art, no science and only they have well adapted to physical environment by evolution of physical body.just big fish eat little fish is the only law.

   Animals never use apparatus to measure time and they synchronise the time with environment. Animals fight for survival not for possess anything. Animals fight, flight, eat, drink, sleep etc…….are the purpose of their existence. Time is passing slowly in this realm
5. Hungry ghosts.

   They always overflow with craving and desire. Mind is driven to fulfil craving and desire and they are not fulfilled by achievements. Time is very slow as they are always in overflow by non-satisfaction.
6. Hell being

   Always suffer from intensive, extreme and unavoidable pain both physically and mentally. But mental pain is the most. (As modern psychiatry says mental suffering is difficult than physical pain) and it is extremely difficult to escape from this realm and time is very very slow in this realm. E.g just imagine a person who is wounded badly and has to suffer intensive pain in hospital ICU units.

Is my explanation of the six realms of existence consistent with common Buddhist explanation?

Comment: Hi D S. This is a question & answer forum. Therefore, I edited to your post to include the question at the end. Regards

Comment: it looks kinda beautiful, thanks

Comment: According to your description and graph, does this mean that the 6 realms are just different states of mind (for a person)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is correct this is the way a mahayana views reality. And this is the reason a theravedan disagrees! LOL.

To the theravedan the six realms are not visible in the human world. Or rather with human eyes the six realms are not visible on earth.

Answer (score -1):

The explanation does not appear to conform with common Buddhist interpretations, which say:

1. Godly realms can still result in suffering (e.g. [AN 4.123](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.123.than.html)) &;
2. The human realm is the ideal place to reach enlightenment & Nibbana; where Nibbana is the highest ([Dhp 203](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.15.budd.html)) & only secure nonfluctuating ([MN 140](https://suttacentral.net/en/mn140)) happiness.

The human realm is described below:

> Sooner, I say, would that blind turtle, coming to the surface once every hundred years, insert its neck into that yoke with a single hole than the fool who has gone once to the nether world would regain the **human state**. For what reason? Because here, bhikkhus, there is no conduct guided by the Dhamma, no **righteous conduct**, no **wholesome activity**, no **meritorious activity**. Here there prevails mutual devouring, the devouring of the weak. For what reason? Because, bhikkhus, they have not seen the Four Noble Truths. What four? The noble truth of suffering … the noble truth of the way leading to the cessation of suffering.
>
> [SN 56.47](https://suttacentral.net/en/sn56.47)

Comment: Does it say there's suffering in the Godly realms? Only that they're impermanent. I'm not even sure Gods acquire any bad kamma there, only that they use up (and, presumably, don't acquire more) good kamma.

Comment: god realm is a state of happiness and it is possible to drop down lower realms.once in god realms no feeling of suffering and saturated with happiness and pleasure.

Comment: Chris, impermanence and clinging is what leads to suffering, so higher realms can have. Suffering simply means "unknown amounts of work ahead". :)

Answer (score -2):

All the lokkas you call "states" are just as real as the robe and the bowl...
Keep calling Buddha a liar; with continual grasping at "mind" and you will feel the realness of the lokkas with body attachment; If you have not already heard them for yourself by hearing the lokkas speech attachment; In "self and other" soon enough.

Do: Practice, practice, practice. Do not: Think, think, think.
Grasping of the eye, ear, nose, mouth, and tactile sensations are each a consciousness and aflame with skandha in each sense consciousness making six jealousy's to break the link... breaking the link of the eye skandhas is just one, consciousness conquered.

At least; Three rounds of birth and death are required to attain the fourth noble step into truth on the path.

The essence of: "Practice as if; One's head is on fire." Is a direct pointing to this.

When you are sitting in your grave; and Mara is tearing your hair out by the roots? Don't forget to smile.

"Whatever an enemy might do to an enemy, or a foe to a foe, the ill-directed mind can do to you even worse."
~Dhammapada

That quote is past tense from someone thus gone sharing their wisdom, worthy of gifts and offerings.

When you yourself find yourself alone in the grave and yet still living? And Mara after Mara of either "Body" "Speech" or "mind" is tearing your hair out by the roots; speaking or growling disembodied; Trying to possess your "precious human form"? As any ol' preta is apt to do? Do not forget; They only see humans as a vessel, an easy to conquer vehicle due to the three poisons the attachment is so strong in craving and desire for the three poisons; not having form? They only want yours as soon as you become untangled.